# how to load to specific folder in aws

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services

I have an aws account setup for file storage.  I am trying to set up the views so that the files get loaded to specific folders and I cannot find an answer that solves this issue.  I have search this site, but was unable to find code like mine and I am somewhat new to php.  My code is take straight from the heroku and aws guides.

My understanding is I have to set a $keyPrefix, but I cannot seem to get it right.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
  // require('vendor/autoload.php');
  // this will simply read AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY from env vars
  $s3 = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory();
  $bucket = getenv('S3_BUCKET')?: die('No "S3_BUCKET" config var in found in env!');
  $keyPrefix = 'assets/avatars/';
?>

<html>
  <head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
  <body>
     <h1>S3 upload example</h1>

     <?php
         if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_FILES['userfile']) && $_FILES['userfile']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
print_r($_FILES, $keyPrefix);

    // FIXME: add more validation, e.g. using ext/fileinfo
    try {
          // FIXME: do not use 'name' for upload (that's the original filename from the user's computer)
         $upload = $s3->upload($bucket, $_FILES['userfile']['name'], fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'rb'), 'public-read');
     ?>
     <p>Upload <a href="<?=htmlspecialchars($upload->get('ObjectURL'))?>">successful</a> :)</p>
     <?php } catch(Exception $e) { ?>
     <p>Upload error :(</p>
     <?php } } ?>
     <h2>Upload a file</h2>
     <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/aws/upload" method="POST">
        <input name="userfile" type="file">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
     </form>
  </body>
```

Comment: Can you describe what the issue you're having is? Specifically, any error messages or what the resulting behavior you see it will help. You can get a better error message by printing `$e->getMessage()` or by not catching the exception (not using `try...catch`), so that we see the error returned. As it is now, it's "eating" the error up so we can't tell what the issue is.

Comment: No error, the file is saving it is just saving to the bucket and I want to place it inside a folder in the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what version of the AWS library you are using, but the latest doesn't appear to have an `upload` method. Instead I suggest using the `putObject` method like the example shows on their  Github page. (Alternatively, check what version of the s3 client you are using and we can see if it's any different).

From the [Github readme which has an example](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php):

```
<?php
// Upload a publicly accessible file. The file size and type are determined by the SDK.
try {
    $s3->putObject([
        'Bucket' => 'my-bucket',
        'Key'    => 'my-object',
        'Body'   => fopen('/path/to/file', 'r'),
        'ACL'    => 'public-read',
    ]);
} catch (Aws\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file.\n";
}
```

More [complete docs are here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html).